# I cannot install my apk into my HTC mobile

Tags: android, mobile

I have an Android HTC mobile with me. When I was running my program with Eclipse its showing an error as

```
BouncingBallSample] ERROR: Application requires API version 7. Device API version is 1 (Android 1.0).
BouncingBallSample] Launch canceled!
```

In the manifest file I have set the sdk version as

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.immersion.bouncingballsample"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BouncingBallActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <application android:debuggable="true" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Which HTC phone are you using, because I have never seen a phone report version 1.

Comment: You have to update your phone, 2.3.3 is a good stable version (most people have this version or higher)

Comment: The simplest way to update you phone is in your phone's settings under about phone. There you will find out what version on Android your device is running as well as a menu called "System Updates". From the System Updates menu you can check to see if there is an OS update available and the last time your phone check for an update. More than likely the version of Android you are running is the lastest available for your device.

Comment: Can you please provide a error log for the force close?

Comment: Yeah, now that it installs, the problem is something different, as mentioned. Please run "adb logcat" from platform-tools, or use the logcat view in Eclipse, and look for a stack trace right after the "application stopped" error message shows up. This will show where your code is running into an error now.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, The the OP edited the question to invalidate the answers (now reverted). Thus, when you look at the code which was in the question, the problem reported by the error included in the question didn't exist.

Comment: @dinesh Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, The point I was trying to make was that for the state in which the question was in, the close voters were technically correct. It was "No Repo". The code wouldn't have produced the error, because the OP had changed the question to correct the problem (which, obviously, also invalidated the answers). Once reverted, the code will produce the error under the conditions specified. So, it should be reopened. Part of why the close-voters would not have seen the issue is that answers are not presented in the close-vote review queue (you have to use a user script to display them).

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />
```

or you can even remove this line if you like, the default is 1.

Extra info: [Android sdk page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Do you still get the same error ?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see you updated your post. The next error means that there is now a problem with your application. The original problem of your post is resolved ;-) (please accept my answer and maybe start another post with the current problem ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `MinSdkVersion` to a lower no like 1 or use `android:targetSdkVersion="1"` in the same tag.